# I can't delete my application

Tags: google-app-engine

I can't delete my application I did for test (a personal website): http://wwwfabiosirnacom.appspot.com/

As you can see in this screenshot the app is not in my dashboard:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhvvwe8k5009jy3/Screenshot%202014-04-21%2015.45.42.png

Is there a way to delete it definitely? Or just overwrite with a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have created the app with a different Google Account, or deleted yourself from the team members of the app.

You should log in with an Google Account that has admin access to the application. Once you figure out which account it is, follow this page:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/applicationsettings#disable_or_delete_your_application

Comment: Thank for your quick reply. I have only an account and I managed the application only with that account. I was one of the first beta tester of Google Apps and I have a free account and I can't contact the support. I think that I've deleted the app from the dashboard, and I can't delete what I've deployed. I think that is something that I can't do from my side. Someone in Google should remove the app from their side. But I can't contact them :(